# SOQL error on enabling namespace

Tags: soql, lightning, error, namespace

I have enabled namespace in my dev org.

Namespace name - LightningMyth.

When I write the following query in any class/trigger,

```
List<Account> acc=[SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT limit 1];
```

I get the error :

> Illegal assignment from `List<Account>` to `List<LightningMyth.Account>`

but the same query works fine in workbench and QueryEditor.

When I changed the query to

`List<LightningMyth.Account> acc=[select id from LightningMyth.Account limit 1];`

I get this error -

> Compile Error: First SObject of the FROM statement must be a valid
>   SObject type.

I get this issue after enabling namespace and this issue is only with Account object, the SOQL with other standard and custom objects works just fine.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your organization, somewhere you might have created a class named "Account". That's why the compiler is not able to understand that whether it is standard Object Account or the class created by you. Please rename your class, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Devendra! I actually had a class named Account. I renamed that class and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaceprefix does not append with Standard objects and fields or components.They only get appended to custom objects and fields or components which are present in the org.

So there is no need to append namespaceprefix with your query on `account` object.

As far as your first query is concerned that looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try prefixing references to the `Account` with `Schema`. When you use `Account` as your class name, it is really shorthand for `Schema.Account`. Using the fully qualified class name will avoid conflict.

For example:

```
List<Schema.Account> acc = [/*query*/];
```